# Passing custom value to PayPal for payment and getting it back in return url

Tags: paypal

I just would like to know if it is possible to send in a custom variable through the PayPal form and get the value passed back on the return URL by PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Check Website Payments Standard Integration Guide, Appendix A

custom
Optional Pass-through variable for your own tracking purposes, which
buyers do not see.
Default – No variable is passed back to you.